# Microsoft C# Chart Control displays false data

Tags: c#, charts

I'm trying to display visits to different websites over time, and it works fine.
But when I try to add another website which I start tracking after I started tracking the other sites, the chart displays it as if I started it together with the other sites.
For example when I have those arrays:

```
{
dates[] { "8/1", "8/2", "8/3" }
visits[] { 100, 74, 96 }
}
{
dates[] { "8/1", "8/2", "8/3" }
visits[] { 52, 86, 23 }
}
```

It works fine.. But when I have those arrays:

```
{
dates[] { "8/1", "8/2", "8/3" }
visits[] { 100, 74, 96 }
}
{
dates[] { "8/3" }
visits[] { 52 }
}
```

It shows me the second as it had 52 visits on 8/1 and not on 8/3

Here's my code:

```
 public void drawChart(List<object[]> data)
        {
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i = i + 3)
            {
                chart1.Series.Add(data[i+2][0].ToString());
                chart1.Series[i / 3].Points.DataBindXY(data[i], data[i+1]);
                chart1.Series[i / 3].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
                chart1.Series[i / 3].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                chart1.Series[i / 3].BorderWidth = 3;
            }
        }
```

The list contains the arrays, first array contains the dates, second one contains the visits and the third contains only one object which is the series name.

Comment: can you plz post some code on how you parse the data into the charts?

Answer (score 0):

see [Microsoft Chart Controls and X-Axis time scale format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605852/mschart-control-x-axis-time-scale-format)

Passing strings as X values turn them into dumb labels I think.
You will need convert them to Date for the axis to be able to position them correctly then use label formatting to display what you want.

```
this.chart.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "DD/MM";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind directly to DateTime?

```
IList<DateTime> listx = new List<DateTime>();
IList<double> listy = new List<double>();

//iterate and add your values to the two lists: listx and listy

//when you're done, bind the lists to the points collection
chart1.Series[i / 3].Points.DataBindXY(listx, listy);
```

Hope this helps :)